# Red Hat Server Backup

Tags: backup, redhat

I am willing to back up my red hat that is being used as tomcat server, it also has oracle on it. The thing is, we will be moving shortly and everything has to work when we move to the other location. Except that, in the case that anything happens to the server while moving, we would have to restore this backup to a dis-similar system. Is it possible to take a hardware-independent bare-metal compatible backup?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) for doing a bare metal backup of your system.

Keep in mind however that might not be necessary.  It's very likely you can get by with just a backup of your data.  If something goes wrong, just set up a new server from scratch and dump your data on on it.  you could do this ahead of time by using clonezilla (or heck, just kickstart) to develop a setup which matches your existing server except for your user data.  That way if you do have to set up a new server to replace the existing one, you already have all your configuration data saved.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to take a
>   hardware-independent bare-metal
>   compatible backup?

Yes and no. Your initrd will be loading drivers specific to your hardware (e.g. IO controllers etc). As such dumping a copy of your server onto different hardware won't necessarily work (but it may!). The chances are you'll have to use a live/rescue CD to rebuild your initrd for the new hardware (easy when you know how!)

Other than that, as long as the architectures match, you should be able to restore to another box OK.